# Microsoft Graph : How get alias email from message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

When a message has sent to an alias email, MS Graph return always principal email in "toRecipients" or in the internet message headers.

I tried :
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/Messages/{id}$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x007D')`

or

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}/Messages/{id}?select=internetMessageHeaders`

Is it possible to recover the alias email with MS Graph in the message properties?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "alias" email? Are you asking for the collection of email addresses assigned to the User?

Comment: Yeah i agree with with @MarcLaFleur. Please explain what you look for.

Comment: if your main username is John@contoso.one and you have an alias of CEO@contoso.one, then when someone sends to the alias CEO@ it still looks like it is "To:" John in Recipients list, because it has already resolved. 

He wants to be able to see if it was sent to CEO@ or John@

Comment: You might be able to find this in the message headers. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/internetmessageheader?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: @Seb I have the same issue where I need the message "To" to tell me which address was used. I want to get the alias email if used. Did you manage to resolve this?